# Fundamental Theorem of linear algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let V be the subspace of all vectors in $R^5$, such that

$x1 −x2 = x3 −x4 = x5$

(a) Find a basis $B1$ of $V$; What is the dimension of $V$?

(b) Find a matrix $D$ with $V$ as its column space. What is the rank of $D$?

Comment: Any thoughts here? Perhaps something about degrees of freedom in the definition of $\;V\;$ ? BTW, what "Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra"?

Comment: It is given as a hint to this exercise: Use FTLA Part 1

Comment: @S That doesn't answer my question: what do **you** call the FTLA to?

Comment: what do you mean specifically?

Comment: @S Just read what I wrote! What do you call FTLA to?? What theorem is that? What does it say??

Comment: There are several parts of the FTLA. See e.g. "The Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra", Gilbert Strang in The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 100, No. 9. (Nov., 1993), pp. 848-855. The question is now which specific "part 1" the hint refers to. Most likely its the one in the above cited paper which states that the dimensions of the range and the nullspace of a $n\times n$-matrix sum up to $n$.

Comment: @DonAntonio FTLA = rank nullity theorem

Comment: Which part of it can be used to solve the problem , best case scenario? I know how to solve part B, if I manage to solve part A. So, reduce my question, to Find a basis B1 of V; What is the dimension of V?

Comment: Since we have to find bases for these spaces, the FTLA doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That name is **far away** from being widely and/or uniformly used, as opposed to the Fundamental Theorem of algegra, the F. T. of arithmetic or the F.T. of (integral) Calculus. Two of the most widely used sites, Wiki and Wolfram, bring two very different versions of it, the second getting into orthonormal basis (GM method and stuff) .

Comment: @DonAntonio I agree.  I just wanted to say something because nobody else was giving you a quick answer.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** We can equivalently say that $V$ is the set of all vectors in $\Bbb R^5$ that satisfy the equations
$$
x_1 - x_2 - x_5 = 0\\
x_3 - x_4 - x_5 = 0
$$
In other words, $V$ is the null space of the matrix 
$$
\pmatrix{1&-1&0&0&-1\\0&0&1&-1&-1}
$$
Now you just need to find a basis of the null space of a matrix.

Comment: Thank you, that solves the problem! Now, we can apply the  rank nullity theorem as @DonAntonio mentioned. Once we know the nullity and the number of columns, we can find the rank.

Comment: As I say in my earlier comment: if you're actually finding bases for these spaces, the FTLA is useless.  The rank is the dimension of the column space.  The dimension of the column space is the number of vectors in its bases.  You have a basis, so just count the number of vectors in the basis.